# Send Parameter Through Object

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and I want to send parameter via an object.
I also have tried to create my objects, but unfortunately it did not work. Here's the code:

```
var obj = (function(foo) {

    var str = foo;

    var bar = function() {
        alert(this.str+" Bar");
    }

})();
```

When I call `obj('foo').bar();`, I want it to produce **foo Bar**. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```js
var obj = function(foo) {
  return {
    bar: function() {
      alert(foo + ' Bar'); 
    }
  }  
}

obj('foo').bar();
```

EDIT: You can even use the "Run code snippent" to test it :)

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of solution for your case. I'll provide my favourite one.

```js
var obj = function(foo) {
  if (!(this instanceof obj)) {
    return new obj(foo);
  }
  this.str = foo;
}
obj.prototype.bar = function() {
  alert(this.str + " Bar");
};
obj('foo').bar();
//or
new obj('foo').bar();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and I am sure you offer a better solution. but when line 2 is executed? and what is obj.prototype? you never declare it

Comment: @Mdkusuma When you call `obj('foo')` without keyword `new`. About the prototype object, you can read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) for further information.